# Connecting a Kinect to Windows 8 computer with Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0

Tags: windows-8, drivers, kinect

Eventually, I want to set up the Kinect sensor with Processing using [Simple OpenNI](https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/)

I'm following [these instructions at Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn782035.aspx). I installed the KinectSDK V2.0-1409. The Kinect Sensor I am using is Xbox360 Kinect model 1414.

I plugged the Kinect into the power adapter and into the USB port and looked in the Device Manager. I see nothing resembling the Kinect under "Audio inputs and outputs", nor under "sound, video and game controllers" as the Microsoft Developer Network suggests I would. I did, however, see under "Other devices", "Xbox NUI Motor".

[image: Device Manager]

I double clicked the Xbox NUI Motor and saw that "the drivers for this device are not installed. To find a driver for this device, click Update Driver."

[image]

I tried searching for a driver through Windows. No luck. I also tried searching manually but couldn't find it.

How can I find the appropriate driver for this?

Comment: Are you sure the 2.0 SDK is for the Kinect 1 and not the Kinect 2?

Comment: @Ramhound not sure about that. Good point. I'll try http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/beta.aspx next.

Comment: Use the correct drivers [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40278) but if this Kinect isn't the one sold for PC you might be out of luck.  Don't use the beta drivers thats just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Ramhound I used those drivers and also followed instructions I found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11585419/370407 . That combination of things worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SDK version 1.8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40278) along with the instructions at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11585419/370407) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can only recognise Xbox NUI Motor, when the power adapter is not connected to electricity.

Make sure that the power adapter is connected and is not damaged

Comment: Your two sentences contradict each other.

Comment: Oh sorry, let me re-arrange the first sentence:
When the power adapter is not connected, windows can only recognise Xbox NUI Motor, (i.e it can't recognize Xbox Camera or Xbox Mic).
Therefore, make sure that the power adapter is connected and is not damaged.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is Xbox One and the adapter for Windows 8
I download this：[Kinect Run time](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44559)

and worked good for me.may could help..

Comment: Wrong Kinect, user is using the first generation hardware, drivers are not applicable to the user.